# Find all second-order polynomial solutions to the Heat Equation

Tags: polynomials, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The following problem is a homework and I am not asking for a solution but simply for a hint on how to approach it. The task is given as follows:

*Find all second-order polynomial solutions to the heat equation:*
$u_{t}-u_{xx}=0$

This is what I have done so far:

Given that $u(t, x)$ is a second-order polynomial, the equation will be the following:

$u(t, x) = ax^2+bxt+ct^2+dx+et+f$  (where $a, b, c, d, e, f$ are constants)

$u_{t}(t, x)=bx+2ct+e$

$u_{x}(t, x)=2ax+bt+d$

$u_{xx}(t, x)=2a$

From what follows that $bx+2ct+e-2a=0$

Is there anything else that I'm missing? 
How should one approach this problem without any previous knowledge of PDEs?

Thanks.

Comment: As your last equality has to be satisfied for all $x$ and for all $t$, you can get more information about the coefficients.

Comment: @Alex, after substituting I ended up with the following expression: $ax^2+2at-ct^2+dx+f=0$. Is this enough or do I need to perform more steps to consider the problem to be solved?

Comment: You had the equation $bx+2ct+e-2a=0$. As this equation has to hold forall x and t, you directly get $b=0=c$ and $e=2a$. From that you can write down you polynomial.